# How to prove there is no function relation between variables?

Tags: functions, relations, function-and-relation-composition

In the follow diagram, z=x*y, p=2*y, p has no relation with x.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GohZi.png)

But according to the set theory definition of function, I can construct the ternary relation $\{(x,y,p)|p=2*y,x\in[0,1],y\in[0,1]\}$ that can satisfy the requirements of a function. So there is a function between p and x,y: p=f(x,y). So is there a function relation between p and x,y or not?

Comment: $p(x,y)=2y$ is a perfectly good function. The function $P(y)=2y$ is also fine, but it is different to p as it has a different domain.

Comment: Part of the difficulty in answering this question is we don't know the context. Where did the diagram come from and what inferences can be drawn from it? (For example, why would you mention $[0,1]$? It is nowhere in the diagram.) Also, how is a "function relation" between variables defined? The set-theoretic definition of a function says nothing about that.

Comment: The question arose when I read tensorflow's compute graph. The inputs are variables in range of [0,1]. Can the output variables and the input variables have function relations? I think so.